# How can I orderBy() a column in an eager loaded relationship in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4, relationship, eager-loading

How would I orderBy a relationships column in a query?

For example I have an $order variable that contains something like 'title.asc', it's then exploded and sent to the query in the model via the controller and I use $order[0] and $order[1] respectively but if the column is on the eager loaded relationships table, how could I use this?

```
public function scopeEvents($query, $order, $course, $supplier, $city, $venue, $eventStatus, $tutor)
{
    $date = date('Y-m-d');

    $query->where('active', 1)
        ->with('course', 'venue', 'supplier', 'eventType', 'eventStatus', 'tutor', 'delegates')
        ->where('start_date', '>=', $date)
        ->orderBy($order[0], $order[1]);

    if ( ! empty($course[0]))
    {
       $query = $query->whereIn('course_id', $course);
    }

    if ( ! empty($supplier[0]))
    {
        $query = $query->whereIn('supplier_id', $supplier);
    }

    if ( ! empty($venue[0]))
    {
        $query->whereIn('venue_id', $venue);
    }

    if ( ! empty($event_status[0]))
    {
        $query->whereIn('event_status_id', $eventStatus);
    }

    if ( ! empty($tutor[0]))
    {
        $query->whereIn('tutor_id', $tutor);
    }
}
```

At the moment I just get a column not found, which is to be expected.

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of something like this http://pastebin.com/FgWg4A66 but it's a bit messy and doesn't seem to work completely. It doesn't error out but it doesn't seem to order them? More than likely because it's actually ordering the returned relationship rather than the events themselves.

Answer (score 1):

In order to reduce load times while also being able to order by related table columns, I had to combine eager loading with joins, and use the joins for ordering and the eager loading to display data in the view. Seems to work well.

```
public function scopeEvents($query, $order, $course, $supplier, $city, $venue, $eventStatus, $tutor)
{
    $date = date('Y-m-d');

    $query->where('active', 1)
        ->with('course', 'venue', 'supplier', 'eventType', 'eventStatus', 'tutor', 'delegates')
        ->leftJoin('courses', 'courses.id', '=', 'events.course_id')
        ->leftJoin('suppliers', 'suppliers.id', '=', 'events.supplier_id')
        ->leftJoin('venues', 'venues.id', '=', 'events.venue_id')
        ->leftJoin('event_types', 'event_types.id', '=', 'events.event_type_id')
        ->leftJoin('event_statuses', 'event_statuses.id', '=', 'events.event_status_id')
        ->leftJoin('tutors', 'tutors.id', '=', 'events.tutor_id')
        ->select('events.*', DB::raw("concat(tutors.first_name,' ',tutors.last_name) as tname"), 'event_statuses.status', 'event_types.type', 'venues.name as vname', 'suppliers.name as sname', 'courses.title', 'venues.city')
        ->where('start_date', '>=', $date)
        ->orderBy($order[0], $order[1]);

    if ( ! empty($course[0]))
    {
       $query = $query->whereIn('course_id', $course);
    }

    if ( ! empty($supplier[0]))
    {
        $query = $query->whereIn('supplier_id', $supplier);
    }

    if ( ! empty($venue[0]))
    {
        $query->whereIn('venue_id', $venue);
    }

    if ( ! empty($event_status[0]))
    {
        $query->whereIn('event_status_id', $eventStatus);
    }

    if ( ! empty($tutor[0]))
    {
        $query->whereIn('tutor_id', $tutor);
    }
}
```